# Limit e-mail flow in Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel, smtp, swiftmailer

I'm working on an app built with Laravel 4.2.

My app will send a pretty large amount of individual emails. The problem is that my SMTP server has a limit of max 300 mails/30 minutes and 5000 mails/day

That will be enough for me. But I would want to control the flow of sen email by queuing them up to be sent at a rate of max 300 mails/30 mins.

Is there a simple way of doing that, using Laravels libraries?

Comment: I found this article interesting: https://www.camroncade.com/limit-the-number-of-messages-sent-on-one-smtp-connection-laravel-5/

Comment: The same question is over here, and I just answered it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53783301/470749

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with the queue. Say you had a DB table with one row for each email to be sent, and a column tracking if that email has been sent. You could create a Laravel [Command](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/commands) that would be executed as a cronjob every 30 minutes that would send the next 300 emails that have not yet been sent.

A better, cleaner and all around more scaleable option would be to implement one of the many queue engines supported by Laravel's [Queues](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues). This will require modification of the server environment much like installing mysql to support the database.